# commenting on an edit

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I can address a comment to the author of a post, or to a user who has commented on the post, but unless I'm missing something there is no way to address a comment to a user who has edited without commenting, so that said editor will be notified. Should there be? (For example, someone edited an answer of mine, adding some useful information, and I wanted to ask him/her about where he/she found the information.)

Comment: I think this has [already been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91971/comment-on-an-edit) on the meta SE site (which would probably be the best place for further requests, since features like this can't be implemented on a per-site basis).

Comment: @BESW According to the comments on the question you linked to, editors *are* notified of comments directed to them. So I guess the answer to my question is that I was missing something. All I know is that when I type @ followed by the first name of the editor, SE does not suggest the full name, as it does e.g. when I addressed this comment to you.

Comment: Even if it doesn't autocomplete, they should get the notification.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, that's good to know. In practice, I guess they will get the notification about half the time--namely, on the occasions when I happen to type their name correctly, which is not so easy without autocomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `@username` syntax in a comment on a post to notify:

- someone who previously commented on the post and whose comment isn't deleted;
- someone who edited the post;
- a moderator who close the post, if it's a question (this only applies to moderator close votes, not to ordinary close votes).

This is in addition to the author of the post, who is always notified.

Completion only suggests the names of previous commenters, because that's the usual case. But `@name-of-editor` will notify an editor. Copy-paste the name from the revision history if you aren't sure to get it right.